# strange issue with git pull from origin branch

Tags: git

A colleague of mine pushed a branch (BranchA) to the repo.

I have then created a copy of this branch (testBranch) from BranchA.

Everything is all well and good.

The colleague then pushed up two further commits to BranchA.

I have then git pull ( to get the latest changes in from the repo)

However, I do not see the two files committed.

**Repo**

BranchA

**Local**

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout testBranch origin/BranchA
git merge master
```

I am not sure why I do not get to see the latest commits(files)

**Workaround:**

1. Deleted the local branch
2. created a fresh branch
3. Checkout master
4. Git pull
5. Checkout new branch
6. git merge
7. I now see the further two commits

I feel as though I am missing a step in here? It feels weird, that I would have to delete the branch each time I am required to get a latest changes from a particular origin/branch

Comment: And where did you pull from his branch to get the two new commits?

Comment: i pulled from origin

Comment: You don't *just* pull from origin, you also pull *a specific branch*, which is either the named branch you pull from, or the configured upstream for your current local branch. But anyway, it seems you pulled from origin *before* you created the branch so I'll repeat the question: Where did you pull from his branch to get the two new commits? I think the answer here is that you never did, thus you never got the two new commits.

Comment: I guess the mistake was that I needed to pull from that particular branch, rather than Master itself. Since this branch was not merged into Master, I would not see the changes.

Answer (score 2):

You're ascribing too much magic to branches. :-)

The way Git works is really remarkably simple.  A *branch name* is simply a name for a single Git commit hash ID.  (I also advise that you forget that `git pull` even exists, but we'll see what it is, soon, and how to use it.)

#### About commits, hash IDs, branch names, and commit chains

Let's talk about these commit hash IDs a bit.  A hash ID is a big ugly string of letters and digits, such as `0d0ac3826a3bbb9247e39e12623bbcfdd722f24c`.  This uniquely identifies some Git object—typically a commit, and when we work with branch names, it's always, definitely, a commit.  Each commit records the hash ID of its *parent*, or predecessor commit.  This allows Git to string commits together into a backwards-looking chain.

What this means is that we can *draw* these commit chains.  If we let a single uppercase letter stand in for the big ugly hash ID, we get something that looks like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

The *name* `master` holds the actual hash ID of commit `H`.  That lets Git *find* `G`, in the sea of commits floating inside the repository.  From `H`, Git can get the hash ID of `G`, which is `H`'s parent.  So now Git can find `G`.  Using `G`, Git can find `F`, and so on, backwards, down the line.  The arrows here can be read as *points to:* `master` points to `H`, `H` points to `G`, and so on.

The contents of each commit are completely, totally, 100% frozen / read-only.  Nothing inside any commit can ever change.  So we don't really need to draw the internal arrows.  However, branch names *do* change.  The way Git adds a *new* commit to `master` is to write out a commit object, storing `H`'s hash ID in the new object, along with the new commit snapshot and any other *metadata* like your name and email address and log message.  This produces a new hash, which we'll call `I` rather than trying to guess it:

```
...--F--G--H--I
```

and now Git simply needs to write the hash ID of `I` into the name `master`, so that `master` now points to `I`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

If you have more than one branch, or if you have multiple *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master` and `origin/BranchA`, we just draw them all:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/BranchA
```

(We'll talk more about remote-tracking names in a moment.  They are kind of like branch names, but with a twist.)

When you create a new branch name, all Git has to do is make the new name point to some existing commit.  For instance, let's create our own `BranchA` now, using `git checkout BranchA`:<sup>1</sup>

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- BranchA, origin/BranchA
```

Now let's create `testBranch` as well, also pointing to commit `J`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- testBranch, BranchA, origin/BranchA
```

If you create a new commit now, your Git needs to know *which branch name to update*.  So your Git has this special name, `HEAD`, written in all-capitals like this.<sup>2</sup>  Git attaches this name to one of your branch names:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- testBranch (HEAD), BranchA, origin/BranchA
```

which means that `testBranch` is the *current* branch, and is therefore the *name that Git will update* when you run `git commit` to make a new commit.  One of the things `git checkout` does is to manage this HEAD-attachment.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since you *don't have* a `BranchA`, you might think: *How can I check it out?*  In fact, you *should* think that: it's a really good question.  The answer is that your Git will *create* your own `BranchA` *from the remote-tracking name*.  That's why you had to `git checkout -b testBranch` but not `git checkout -b BranchA`: the `-b` flag says *create*, and without it, Git will only create if the name doesn't exist *and* there's a remote-tracking name that *does* exist that looks right.  There's more to it than this, but that's a good start.

<sup>2</sup>Due to a quirk, you can usually use lowercase `head` on Windows and MacOS, but not on Unix-like systems like Linux.  It's advisable to avoid this habit, since it won't work on Linux: if you don't like typing `HEAD` in all caps, use `@`, which is a synonym for the magic name.

---

#### Remote-tracking names, or, what happens when someone makes commits in some other Git repository?

The thing about these branch names is that they're *specific to **your** Git repository*.  Your `master` is **your** `master`.  Your `BranchA` is your `BranchA` and your `testBranch` is yours, too.  They won't change unless *you* change them.

In fact, even your remote-tracking names—`origin/master` and `origin/BranchA`—are yours too, but what makes them remote-tracking names is that your Git will *automatically* change them, to remember what your Git sees in some other Git, whenever your Git calls up their Git and asks them about *their* branch names.  That is, your Git has the URL for some other Git repository, listed under the *remote* name `origin`: `origin` is a short name for some long, maybe-hard-to-type URL.  You can run:

```
git fetch origin
```

and your Git will call up their Git, at the URL listed under `origin`, and ask their Git about *their* branches.  They'll say: *Oh, sure, here you go: my `master` is <hash1> and my `BranchA` is <hash2>.*  (To see this, run `git ls-remote origin`, which is like `git fetch origin` except that after getting the listing of remote names and hashes, it just prints them out.)

With this list in hand, your Git goes on to ask their Git for any *new* commits *they* have that you don't.  So if they've updated *their* `BranchA`, you get their new commits.  Then, regardless of what else has happened, your Git now sets all of your *remote-tracking names* that start with `origin/`.  That is, suppose their had two new commits.  Your own repository now looks like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- testBranch (HEAD), BranchA
                 \
                  K--L   <-- origin/BranchA
```

Your own `BranchA` and `testBranch` **have not moved**.  These are *your* branches, so they only move when *you* move them.  Your `origin/master` hasn't moved because their `master` hasn't moved, but your `origin/BranchA` *has* moved, to remember new commit `L` that you just got from them, because *their* `BranchA` did move, and now points to this same commit `L`.

(Remember, our uppercase letters stand in for actual big ugly unique hash IDs.  If they made new commits, and you've made new commits, Git guarantees that *their* new hash IDs are different from *every* new commit hash you've made!  You can see that with an active repository, single uppercase letters would run out way too fast, and be too hard to make unique.  But they're a lot easier to draw and make it easier for us to talk about the commits, so that's why I use them here.)

#### Making your branch names move

Now that they've updated *their* `BranchA`, you might want to have your own `BranchA` move too.  This is where things can start to get complicated, but let's look at an easy way to do that.

We'll start by running `git checkout BranchA` again.  This will attach `HEAD` to `BranchA`, so that Git commands that use the *current branch* are using `BranchA`.  Then we'll use `git merge`, which in this case, doesn't actually do any merging!

```
git checkout BranchA
git merge origin/BranchA
```

Before the `git merge`, we have this in our repository:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- testBranch, BranchA (HEAD)
                 \
                  K--L   <-- origin/BranchA
```

The `git merge` looks at `origin/BranchA` and finds that it's pointing to `L`.  It looks at our current branch—the one `HEAD` is attached to—and finds that it's pointing to `J`.  It realize that, by starting at `L` and working backwards, it can get straight to `J`.  This means that the branch name `BranchA` can be "slid forwards", as it were, against the direction of the internal, backwards-pointing arrows.  Git calls this operation a *fast-forward*.  In the context of `git merge`, it's more like a `git checkout` that moves the current branch name.  That is, commit `L` becomes the *current commit*, but it does so by *moving the name `BranchA`*.  The result is:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- testBranch
                 \
                  K--L   <-- BranchA (HEAD), origin/BranchA
```

You now have commit `L` as your current commit, and commit `L` is filling in the *index* and the *work-tree*.  It's time to talk a little bit about these two.

#### The index and the work-tree

We already mentioned that files stored inside commits are completely, totally, 100% frozen / read-only.  They're stored in a special, compressed, Git-only format.  This lets Git save a lot of space, and re-use unchanged files: if a new commit has mostly the same files as the previous commit, there's no need to save all the files.  The old commit's copies are frozen, so the new commit can just *share* them.  (The details by which this process works don't really matter here, but Git uses hash IDs, with what Git calls *blob objects*, to achieve this trick.)

That's great for Git, but we can't use frozen compressed Git-only files to do anything *else*.  So Git has to thaw out and de-compress the frozen files, into their normal everyday form, so that we and the rest of the programs on our computer can *use* them.

The thawed-out files go into the *work-tree*, which is called that because that's where we work on them.  Here, we can do anything we want with our files.  So, for each file, there's a frozen copy in the current commit, and a thawed copy in the work-tree.  (There may be frozen copies in other commits too, but the one in the *current* commit is the most interesting, since we can and will often compare it to the one in the work-tree.)

The *index*, which is also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*, is a peculiar thing, unique to Git.  Other version control systems also have frozen commits and thawed work-trees, but either don't *have* an index, or keep anything index-like totally hidden so that you don't need to know about it.  Git, on the other hand, will, now and then, whack you in the face with the index.  You *must* know about it, even if you don't use it for fancy tricks.

What the index holds is, essentially, a copy of each file.  That is, each file in the *current commit* is *also* in the index.  The index copy is in the special Git-only format.  Unlike the frozen commit copy, though, this one is only semi-frozen—kind of slushy, if you will.  You can *replace* it any time with a new, different, Git-ified and semi-frozen copy.  That's what `git add` does: it Git-ifies the work-tree copy of the file, compressing it into the Git-only format and replacing the previous index copy.  (If the new one matches *any* old one, in any frozen Git commit, it winds up re-using that old one: saving space!  Otherwise it's a new Git-ized copy.)

Making a *new* commit, in Git, just needs to flash-freeze these index copies.  They're all already ready for that, which is a significant part of why `git commit` is so much faster than other version control systems.  But it also means that the index can be described as **what will go into your next commit**.  Git builds new commits from the index, not from the work-tree.

You need the work-tree to work on your files.  Git needs, and uses, the index to make new commits.  The index and work-tree copies can differ; it's part of *your* job to `git add` the work-tree copies, to overwrite the index copies with updated ones, before committing.

#### Updating your `testBranch`

With all that out of the way, let's look now at updating your `testBranch`.  Remember, we ran `git fetch` to update all our `origin/*` names, then `git checkout BranchA` and `git merge origin/BranchA` to update `BranchA`, so that we now have this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- testBranch
                 \
                  K--L   <-- BranchA (HEAD), origin/BranchA
```

We now need to `git checkout testBranch` to attach `HEAD` to it.  Then we can run `git merge BranchA` or `git merge origin/BranchA`:

```
git checkout testBranch
git merge <anything that identifies commit L>
```

The idea here is to make Git look at commit `L`.  The merge command will then see whether or not it's possible to do the same fast-forward operation it did for `BranchA`.  The answer will be yes: it's definitely possible to go from commit `J` straight to commit `L`.  So by default, Git will do just that, and you will get this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J
                 \
                  K--L   <-- testBranch, BranchA, origin/BranchA
```

Note that we can do this even if we *never create our own `BranchA`*, because instead of `git merge BranchA` we can run `git merge origin/BranchA`.  That is, if we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- testBranch (HEAD)
                 \
                  K--L   <-- origin/BranchA
```

and run `git merge origin/BranchA`, Git will do the exact same fast-forward that it would have done with the version with a name `BranchA` pointing to commit `L`.  *What matters here are not the branch names, but rather the commits.*  Well, our own branch names, like `testBranch`, matter, in that we need to make them point where they should; but the *other* names—the remote-tracking names—we only use them to *find the commits*.  They're just *more readable* than hash IDs, and our Git will *automatically update them on `git fetch`*.

Hence, suppose we never created `BranchA` in the first place.  Suppose instead we did:

```
$ git clone <url>
$ cd <repository>
$ git checkout -b testBranch origin/BranchA
... wait until colleague updates origin/BranchA ...
$ git fetch                      # defaults to using origin
$ git merge origin/BranchA
```

then we'd be done, without having to fiddle with *our* `BranchA` that we never even created.

I'm going to omit what happens, here, if you make your own commits.  In this case, you get a true merge—`git merge` will see that it's *not* possible to just fast-forward, and will run the process of merging, and then make a commit of type *merge commit*.  Instead, let's just address the last bit of the puzzle, `git pull`.

#### About `git pull` (don't use it!)

My advice for `git pull` is that as a beginner, you should studiously *avoid* it.  However, other people and documentation will tell you to use it, so you should at least know what it does.  All that `git pull` is and does is to run *two* Git commands for you.  It's meant to be convenient.  The problem is, sometimes it is convenient, and sometimes it's remarkably *not*-convenient.  It's much better, in my opinion, to learn to use the two underlying Git commands first.

The first Git command that `git pull` runs is just `git fetch`.  We already saw that that does: it calls up some other Git, gets a list from it of *its* branch names (and tag names) and hash IDs, and brings into your repository whatever commits you need, so that your Git can update all your *remote-tracking names*.  Then it's done: nothing has happened to your index and work-tree.  It's safe to run `git fetch` *at any time*, because it just adds new commits and updates remote-tracking names.

The *second* command that `git pull` runs is where the trouble comes in.  You can choose *which* second command it runs.  Normally, that's `git merge`, which does what we saw above.  But you can make it run `git rebase`, which we have not covered here.

In either case, `git pull` passes some extra arguments to the `git merge` or `git rebase` command.  These extra arguments cause some of the inconvenience, because they are *different* from the arguments you might want to use.  In particular, if you run:

```
git pull origin master
```

this has the effect of running:

```
git fetch origin master
git merge -m "merge branch 'master' of $url" origin/master
```

Note the slash here in the last argument—Git is going to merge the commit now identified by your `origin/master`.  The `-m` (message) contains the URL taken from `origin`, plus the name `master`, rather than the name `origin/master`, but the *effect* of the merge—whether fast-forward or real merge—is the same as merging your updated remote-tracking name, `origin/master`.<sup>3</sup>

If you use separate `git fetch` and `git merge` commands, they make more sense.  When you use `git pull`, the branch name you list, if you list one, is the name *on the other Git*, rather than the remote-tracking name in *your* Git.

The same holds even if you have `git pull` run `git rebase` for you.  And, in the last twist of being *not*-convenient, the decision of whether to use merge or rebase is one you sometimes should make *after* running `git fetch`.  That is, you should look at *what `git fetch` fetches*, to decide which second command to run.  But if you use `git pull`, you must make this decision *before* you run `git fetch`, so you *can't* look.

Once you have used Git for a while, and are very familiar with both `git merge` and `git rebase`, *then* you can start using `git pull` safely.  (But I still mostly don't.)

---

<sup>3</sup>There's another wrinkle here, with fairly old versions of Git: before Git version 1.8.4, `git pull` *didn't* update the remote-tracking name.  Modern Git does away with this weird quirk, but some systems still use really old Git versions, so it's important to know about.

Comment: This is a great answer for a newbie! I am aware of a lot of what you have mentioned here. I guess I did put a lot of emphasis on "branch" for this question. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You have made a new branch `testBranch` from `BranchA`. And your colleague pushed changes into `BranchA`. But you're still at `testBranch`. So your remote branch has no changes for you to pull and that explains why the commits in `BranchA` isn't seen in `testBranch`

```
...--o--o--*            <-- BranchA
```

You created a copy of brach BranchA.

```
git checkout -b testBranch

...--o--o--*            <-- BranchA, testBranch
```

New commits in BranchA

```
            A--B--C    <-- BranchA
            /
...--o--o--*            <-- testBranch
```

Comment: local BranchA changes were pushed to origin/BranchA and then I did a pull from repo.